# Android PagerTabStrip - Remove spacing

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

Has anyone managed to bring the items in a V4 PagerTabStrip together, more like Google Play Store?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html

This is what I want:

[image: Good Play Store PagerTabStrip]

This is what i get (the space between segments):

[image: V4 Support PagerTabStrip]

These images are not mine but its just to explain what I mean.

Additionally the underline for the Strip, is it possible to have a different color then the selected item underline (v4).

Thanks

***Edit: For all those asking if I ever found a solution, I never did. Sorry :-(***

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: interested in a solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's been a while on this topic but I believe there are people still searching for this answer so I wanted to put here what I've found.

https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabStrip.html

On Android's developer website, they have sample code on how to accomplish it yourself. I personally haven't tested it yet so not sure if it supports that exact look and feel or whether it supports customization but at least the code is there for yourself and you can play around with it. I'd really wish that v4 PagerTitleStrip and PagerTabStrip supported the above features by default.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also searching the answers to this questions and it seems not exist the api to do such thing in `android-support-v4`.

But as an alternative, we can try this https://github.com/xiaopansky/PagerSlidingTabStrip .

Not a perfect but time-saving solution.

Answer (score 0):

The default PagerTitleStrip has only 3 textviews initialized. So if You wish to remove spacing create a custom PagerTitleStrip class and add more textviews so that space is reduced.